# OCaml: Reference to undefined global `A`

Tags: ocaml

I have a three signatures `A.mli`,`B.mli`,and `C.mli`. Within them I have submodules `Aa`, `Bb`, and `Cc` respectively and also a signature for the implementations `Ai`, `Bi`, and `Ci`.

I have implemented them in a file called `D.ml` which looks like this

```
open A
open B
open C

module Ai : Aa = struct ... end
module Bi : Bb = struct ... end
module Ci : Cc = struct ... end
```

I compile them each in turn with the following commands:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core A.mli
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core B.mli
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core C.mli
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core D.ml
```

which all succeed.

I then have a file `E.ml` where I try to use the modules `Ai`, `Bi`, `Ci`.

```
open A
open B
open C

module M = Ai(Ci)

(* do something else *)
```

However when I try to compile `E.ml` I get the

```
Error: Error while linking E.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `A`
```

I think I have to somehow include `D.ml` in the compilation step but I'm unsure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ocamlc` or `ocamlopt` compiler directly (even with the help of `ocamlfind`) is not an easy task, and should be left only for those, who write OCaml tools and very sure in what they're doing. So, in short, just use `ocamlbuild`, that is the default way of compiling things in OCaml world. Since, you're using `Core` library it would be also a good idea to use `corebuild` instead of `ocamlbuild`. `corebuild` is shipped with core, and is actually a small wrapper around `ocamlbuild`, that adds core dependencies, as well as some handy flags. So, with `corebuild` you can compile just with:

```
 corebuild E.native
```

Without `corebuild`, you can compile with

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg core E.native
```

`ocamlbuild` will do all the work for you, i.e., find all dependencies, sort them in correct order, invoke proper tools, etc... You just need this one, command.

If you're still interested in how to compile your example project properly, then you can ask `ocamlbuild` about this. Use `-classic-display` option, that will show you all intermediate commands,

```
 ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -classic-display -pkg core E.byte
```

Will show you all steps. (You may need to `ocamlbuild -clean`, so that you can see all the steps from the start).

Comment: I just tried `corebuild E.native` but I now have the error:

`"Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         A referenced from E.cmx"` which is in `D.ml`

Comment: in general if you have `a.mli`, this means that you need `a.ml`. Compiler will build `a.ml` to produce compiled object `a.cmo` and build interface to produce compiled interface `a.cmi`. Then it will compare, that `a.cmo` implements the specified interface. In your particular example, you need to provide implementation for the A,B and C modules.

Comment: So there is no way to tell `corebuild` that I want it to look into `defaults.ml` for the implementations?

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to `open D` in `E.ml` in order to get the compilation to work.

Comment: `ocamlbuild clean` doesn't appear to be an actual OCamlbuild target.

Comment: fixed, I meant `ocamlbuild -clean`